# CentralFileCommunicationException When Using OpenAndActivateDocument

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

We receive Revit model from other companies, so those models are not central models or local models, or have access to their central model location.  I created, what I thought, was a simple routine to open the received model, detached, so I can save it as a new central model on our network.

```
ModelPath path = ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath(@"C:\Temp\received model.rvt");

OpenOptions opts = new OpenOptions();
opts.Audit = true;
opts.AllowOpeningLocalByWrongUser = true;
opts.DetachFromCentralOption = DetachFromCentralOption.DetachAndPreserveWorksets;
opts.SetOpenWorksetsConfiguration(new WorksetConfiguration(WorksetConfigurationOption.OpenAllWorksets));

UIDocument uidoc = this.OpenAndActivateDocument(path, opts, false);
```

The code works as expected in all but ONE case: when the received file has it's a Workset Configuration of "Specify...".  No matter what WorksetConfiguration I use to try and open the Document, I get the exception.

When I look at the journal file, where the open fails I have this message:

```
Observable::getWorksetConfigForLoading 'Specify' = askUser
```

I've tried using, WorksetConfigurationOption.OpenAllWorksets, WorksetConfigurationOption.CloseAllWorksets and WorksetConfigurationOption.OpenLastViewed.  I'm in Revit 2016, 2018 and 2020.

Comment: The error is related to the "Specify..." being set AND the central model not being available.  If I use the GUI to open the file detached and save it as a new central model on our server, I can use the OpenAndActivateDocument method to open the file and then prompts for me to Specify which worksets to open (even though I'm using the WorksetConfigurationOption.OpenAllWorksets in my OpenOptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the three levels of [Detecting and Handling Dialogues and Failures](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.32). Maybe the Failure API will help, or the JtClicker Windows API hook approach.

Comment: The FailuresProcessing and DialogBoxShowing events are not firing, so I'm not sure how I could catch whatever is causing the error.